# GWT UiBinder: Widget Attribute Listing anywhere?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am trying to use GWT's UiBinder scheme - which should simplify things in creating UI's.

The problem is that I just cannot find any documentation listing each Widget's attribute set that can be specified in the ui.xml file.

Is there such a listing and if yes, can someone point me to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html. There it is written:

> Every one of the widget's methods that follow JavaBean-style conventions for setting a property can be used this way.

Simply put: Every setter method can be used as attribute in the `ui.xml` without the `set`. E.g., there is a `setText(String)` method in `TextField` so you can call this method by writing

```
<g:TextField ... text="foo" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for that; I had gathered that actually, but surely there are other means to using the UiBinder. For example, how do you specify the items in a ListBox? There is no corresponding setter method in ListBox  to add items. Also, what about set methods that take more than one parameter? Can you specify more than one value in UiBinder? Sigh... GWT is a great toolkit, but the documentation is seriously lacking!